# How to fix Overflow: Math range error

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, python-3.3

Whenever I enter in this code, I get an `OverflowError: math range error` at the 4th line. How do I fix it?

```
x=0
while True:
    x=int(x)+1
    first_root=first_root-((a*(math.pow(first_root, 3)))+(b*(math.pow(first_root, 2))+(c*first_root)+d)/(3*(a*   (math.pow(first_root, 2))))+(2*(b*first_root))+c)
    if x==30:
        break
```

Comment: What is `first_root` initialized to?

Comment: first thing, seperate that line to at least 4 different lines.

Comment: And, what are `a` and `b` initialized to?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that the equation you are using **does not have a root**. you can see this by using a `print first_root` statement inside your while loop and seeing that it diverges to +-inf.

However, assuming your textbook isn't screwing with you, and the equation does have a root I can almost guarantee that you have a **parenthesis in the wrong spot**. Below is your exact code with all of the unneeded parenthesis removed and `first_root` replaced with `r` to make it easier to read.

```
r = r - a*pow(r, 3) + b*(pow(r, 2) + c*r + d) / 3*a*pow(r, 2) + 2*b*r + c
```

What you need to do is compare this with the equation in your book and see where/if you messed it up.

Comment: BTW, my guess is that the first "b" should only be multiplied by r^2 and not the other terms.